# Error installing Microsoft CRM 64 bit setup for 64 bit Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm

I have selected correct setup for installing MS CRM for 64 bit Outlook 2013.
Still, the error log shows me following error  : Setup cannot continue because 64-bit Microsoft Office Outlook is installed, please run 64-bit Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook setup.

Following are my software configuration details :

-OS : Windows 7(64 bit)

-Outlook 2013 (64 bit)

-Microsoft Office : Professional Plus 2013 (64 bit)

- Setup run : CRM2016-Client-ENU-amd64 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50370)

-Note - Also tried with setup CRM2013-Client-ENU-amd64

Error Message : The installation has failed. EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Click the link below to view the log file.